# How do I define a function that takes a variadic class template?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to define a simple variant-based Result type alias, sort of like a poor man's rust-like Result type
:

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <typename SuccessType, typename... ErrorTypes>
struct Result {
  using type = std::variant<SuccessType, ErrorTypes...>;
};

template <typename... ErrorTypes>
struct Result<void, ErrorTypes...> {
  using type = std::variant<std::monostate, ErrorTypes...>;
};
}  // namespace detail

template <typename SuccessType, typename... ErrorTypes>
using Result_t = detail::Result<SuccessType, ErrorTypes...>::type;
```

i.e. a `Result_t` is just an `std::variant` where the `0`th index is the successful result and the rest are error structs.

I defined this helper method to check if the result is good:

```cpp
template <typename SuccessType, typename... ErrorTypes>
inline bool Ok(const Result_t<SuccessType, ErrorTypes...>& r) {
  return r.index() == 0;
}
```

But I get a "no matching overloaded function found" when I try to instantiate it:

> error C2672: 'Ok': no matching overloaded function found
>
> error C2783: 'bool Ok(const detail::Result<SuccessType,ErrorTypes...>::type &)': could not deduce template argument for 'SuccessType'

```cpp
struct FileError {};
struct BadJson {};

template <typename T>
using Result = Result_t<T, FileError, BadJson>;

Result<void> GetVoid() { return {}; }

TEST(ConfigFileTest, Result) {
  auto res = GetVoid();
  EXPECT_EQ(res.index(), 0);
  
  bool ok = Ok(res);
  EXPECT_TRUE(ok);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? If I just have `Ok` be templated like `template <typename T> Ok(const T& r)` it works, but makes the function too general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After expanding the `Result_t` alias in the function parameter, it looks like this:

```
template <typename SuccessType, typename... ErrorTypes>
bool Ok(const detail::Result<SuccessType, ErrorTypes...>::type& r) {
  return r.index() == 0;
}
```

The problematic part here is that the template parameters are left of the name resolution operator `::`. Everything left of `::` is a *non-deduced context*, meaning that it is not used to deduce template arguments. So since `SuccessType` and `ErrorTypes...` appear only in non-deduced context, they cannot be deduced and a call which doesn't explicitly specifies them will fail.

You can see that this rule is necessary, because theoretically any specialization of `detail::Result<SuccessType, ErrorTypes...>` could have a `::type` that matches the arguments type. There is no way that the compiler can check this for every possible combination of types.

Instead of trying to alias types, make `Result` an actual new type:

```
template <typename SuccessType, typename... ErrorTypes>
struct Result {
  using variant_type = std::variant<SuccessType, ErrorTypes...>;
  variant_type variant;
};

template <typename... ErrorTypes>
struct Result<void, ErrorTypes...> {
  using variant_type = std::variant<std::monostate, ErrorTypes...>;
  variant_type variant;
};

template <typename SuccessType, typename... ErrorTypes>
bool Ok(const Result<SuccessType, ErrorTypes...>& r) {
  return r.variant.index() == 0;
}
```

or something along those lines. If you really want to use the old design using only aliases, then the function should not take the nested alias as argument, but the actual type instead (which is probably not match the intent of the design):

```
template <typename T, typename... ErrorTypes>
bool Ok(const std::variant<T, ErrorTypes...>& r) {
  return r.index() == 0;
}
```

(I removed the `inline` on the templates. `inline` on a function template doesn't really make much sense.)

Comment: Ah, I suppose I see why the restriction is necessary, thank you. Going the dedicated types route seems tempting so I can also restrict the interface of the type.

Comment: Hmm. As I try to go forward with creating a separate `Result` type, I realize that I'd have to re-implement all of the fancy SFINAE-filled constructors, operator='s, etc. that `std::variant` comes with by default. Maybe the alias is still the way to go for me, unless you have any advice for avoiding rewriting all that boilerplate?

Comment: @MHebes You can of course inherit from `std::variant` (and also inherit the constructors) instead of using composition. If you really just want a strong type alias that should be fine but then your library type's interface will directly be affected by changes in `std::variant`'s interface. Unfortunately C++ currently has no way of automating a wrapper forwarding constructors/member functions to a member. Maybe it will be possible when we get reflection at some point.